# Create a test DataContract object with some internal properties?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a data contract Foo with the following structure.

```
 [DataContract]
 public sealed class Foo
 {
     [DataMember]
     public String Type
     {
         get;
         internal set;
     }
  }
```

For testing purpose I want to create a instance of Foo with a particular type, but I can't set the Type property after creating its instance because it is an internal property. How can I achieve this?

One idea is to create a serialized version of the object and then use the deserializer to create the instance of the object, is this possible, and if yes how can I do it?

Comment: Do you have a separate test assembly? Did you try specifying the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute for test assembly? This way you can access internal members.

Comment: Yes, I have a seperate test assembly. I know of the `InternalsVisibleTo ` property. I was trying to find some other way which is specific for Data Contracts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalVisibleTo` attribute in the product assembly to mark internals visible to test assembly.

In your `AssemblyInfo.cs` file:

```
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("YourTestAssembly.dll, PublicKey=123456")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have 2 constructors on your class:

```
public Foo ();

public Foo (string type) {
    Type = type;
}
```

And use second constructor for testing.

Comment: What if I am not allowed to change the object structure?

Comment: Code always needs to be written as testable. If you cannot change the code, then you cannot test it.. Adding a constructor is not changing the data contract in your case.

Comment: Then, you can use System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalVisibleTo to provide internals access to test Project.